# How do I view SQL generated statement for Update, Delete and Insert with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

For select it is easy and the solution is here

[How do I view the SQL generated by the Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework)

But what about Update, Delete and Insert?

I'm using EF version 4.

Comment: look at http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/tool-tracker/2011/11/seeing-the-sql.aspx

Answer (score 0):

run SQL server profiler and watch the queries executed, that should do it

Answer (score 0):

SQL profiler is an option (and you can luckily use "Application Name" "EntityFramework" (or similar that might not be exactly it) to target EF queries.

In addition to SQL profiler, here's an article from Julie Lerman (one of the leading EF peoples):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx

EDIT:

also here are a few other options in this SO question: [How do I view the SQL generated by the Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412863/how-do-i-view-the-sql-generated-by-the-entity-framework?lq=1)